# Installing Tomcat 7.0.22 on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: tomcat, terminal, osx-lion, tomcat7

I have Mac OS X 10.7. I am following http://wolfpaulus.com/journal/mac/tomcat7 to install Tomcat. Following are the commands on my terminal, but nothing happens after the last line as its given in the guide. Why so?

```
Last login: Fri Oct 14 00:22:53 on ttys000
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ sudo mkdir /usr/local
Password:
mkdir: /usr/local: File exists
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ sudo mv ~/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.22 /usr/local
mv: rename /Users/Vinisa/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.22 to /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.22: Directory not empty
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ sudo ln -s /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.22 /Library/Tomcat
ln: /Library/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.22: File exists
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ sudo chown -R Vinisa /Library/Tomcat
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ sudo chmod +x /Library/Tomcat/bin/*.sh
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗
```

Thanks!

Comment: btw you don't have to type "sudo" each time. Just start a shell with admin privs using the following command: sudo sh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to start the server:

```
/Library/Tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

And point the browser to

```
http://localhost:8080
```

To see if it is working.

Answer (score 2):

I am telling you I roamed all over the web & it would be a piece of cake after this. Just follow one by one

1)Type tomcat in google 
2) Click on the website tomcat.apache.org

3) go to downloads -> tomcat 7 then scroll down to core

4) click on `tar.gz` (2nd option there)
5) open terminal and change directory to the folder where the apache-tomcat-7.0.40 is present 
(use cd foldername) 
6) type

```
sudo chmod +x *.sh
```

(it is used to give exectuable privelages to the files)

7) type

```
sh startup.sh
```

it will work and just display some lines like : 


    Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Users/Sriharshaa/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.40
    Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Users/Sriharshaa/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.40
    Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Users/Sriharshaa/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/temp
    Using JRE_HOME:        /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_13.jdk/Contents/Home
    Using CLASSPATH:       /Users/Sriharshaa/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Users/Sriharshaa/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/bin/tomcat-juli.jar 


8) go to browser type

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

and if you get tomcat website then , tomcat is installed on your computer successfully !

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's a wrong path. The correct path might be as follows,

```
sudo chmod +x /Library/Tomcat/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/*.sh
```